# Reduce size of vector in MEX-file

Tags: matlab, mex

Given a typed vector like this

```cpp
matlab::data::ArrayFactory Factory;
matlab::data::TypedArray<double> BigArray = Factory.createArray({420, 1});
```

How can I shrink `BigArray` size without (re)allocations? All I want is to set its internal length-dimension to a value smaller than 420.

Comment: MATLAB arrays need to be contiguous, you cannot extract a portion without copying the data. If you share how you'll use the smaller array, we might be able to come up with work-arounds.

Comment: I don't want to touch the conitguos property of the array. If you think of an array as a combination of a length-property, a allocated-size-property and its data-pointer-property. All i want is to reduce its length by like 4. I don't care if it has some over-allocated data afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well supposing you spring for the C API instead of the C++ API, you can use `mxSetN` or `mxSetM` on the `mxArray` object to reduce it.

```
int M = 420;
int N = 1;
mxArray *BigArray = mxCreateNumericMatrix(M, N, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
mxSetM(BigArray, M - 4);
```